# Both $push and $addToSet doesn't work as expected

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am creating my collection field as follow:

```
comments: {
        type: [String, String],
        label: 'CommentsLabel',
        optional: true,
},
```

I want the comments to have key, value pair that holds the user id as the key and his comment as the value,

When I try to enter value into the collection as follow:
`Drawings.update({_id: id}, {$set: {comments: [Meteor.userId(), document.getElementById('commentTextArea').value]}})`

The values are successfully stored in the collection:

[image: Comments values in the database]

the problem is that the above code overrides the values, I want the user to push into the array as new comment with the new key, value pair, and I have tried both `$push` as well as `$addToSet` as follows:

```
Drawings.update({_id: id}, {$push: {comments:[Meteor.userId(), document.getElementById('commentTextArea').value]}});

Drawings.update({_id: id}, {$addToSet: {comments:[Meteor.userId(), document.getElementById('commentTextArea').value]}});
```

and both `$push` and `$addToSet` return the following error in the console:

```
update failed: Error: CommentsLabel must be a string (comments.0) in drawings update
    at getErrorObject (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2.js?hash=a69577047db366439087c686b90f269a3cd3a56a:579:17)
    at doValidate (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2.js?hash=a69577047db366439087c686b90f269a3cd3a56a:548:13)
    at Collection.Mongo.Collection.<computed> [as update] (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_collection2.js?hash=a69577047db366439087c686b90f269a3cd3a56a:297:14)
    at Object.click #addComment (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=e62868eba963926f7b9df35445920518c27ffe15:2303:18)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a20deb597f76789e171a9ee2b2e37d73fbb7ecda:3630:20
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a20deb597f76789e171a9ee2b2e37d73fbb7ecda:3575:14)
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a20deb597f76789e171a9ee2b2e37d73fbb7ecda:3629:25)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a20deb597f76789e171a9ee2b2e37d73fbb7ecda:2426:28
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a20deb597f76789e171a9ee2b2e37d73fbb7ecda:2109:12)
    at Blaze._DOMRange.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a20deb597f76789e171a9ee2b2e37d73fbb7ecda:2425:24)
```

I tried the following:

```
var commentsLength = Drawings.findOne({_id: id}).comments.length;
                Drawings.update({_id: id}, {$set: {'comments.commentsLength':[Meteor.userId(), document.getElementById('commentTextArea').value]}});
```

But I get restriction related error in the console even though I am using `$set` operator :slight_smile:

`update failed: Access denied. In a restricted collection you can only update documents, not replace them. Use a Mongo update operator, such as '$set'.`

Not that even when I use `$push` operator, I get the same restriction error

below is my allow and deny rules for the collection:

```
Drawings.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc){
        return !!userId;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc){
        return true;
    },
    remove: function(userId, doc){
        return doc.authorId === userId;
    }
});
```

How to properly add new key and value pairs to the comments array?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save multiple values in array, you should try updating your schema to array of objects instead of array of strings. Like this,

```
"comments" : [ 
    {
        "uid" : "1",
        "comment" : "comm"
    }
]
```

and then you can use your query to push, it will work fine then

```
db.getCollection('drawings').update(
    { _id: 1 }, 
    { $push: { 
        comments: { uid: "2", comment: "comm3" } 
    } 
})
```

or in your case

```
Drawings.update(
    {_id: id}, 
    {$push: { comments:{ uid: Meteor.userId(), comment: document.getElementById('commentTextArea').value }}}
);
```